# Spring injecting values by annotation into implemented spring class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a question how to inject values into implemented by spring class I don't want use xml to define that values like in this piece

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
<property name="host" value="your.smtphost.com"/>
<property name="port" value="25"/>
<property name="username" value="yourusername"/>
<property name="password" value="yourpassword"/>
<property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
        <!-- Use SMTP-AUTH to authenticate to SMTP server -->
        <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
        <!-- Use TLS to encrypt communication with SMTP server -->
        <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

I would like to do it by annotation. I know there is method to extend that class but maybe there is another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotation driven spring configuration for this as shown below

```
@Configuration
class SpringConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender(){
        JavaMailSenderImpl object = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        object.setXXX(ABC);
        .....
        return object;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So if there are other possibilities and someone use something different not the xml configuration please share ;)